# Non-portable Excel VBA macro behavior

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I'm using Excel 2010 and adding a small VBA macro to a spreadsheet.  (The purpose of the macro is to take the data on the active sheet and export it to a CSV file, but that's tangential to the question.)  The macro determines the output path for the file using `ThisWorkbook.Path`.  I also added a custom button to the Quick Access Toolbar to activate the macro.

After getting a working algorithm in place in my experimental spreadsheet (Test.xlsm, stored in one path), I made a copy of the spreadsheet in another path and renamed it to _Database.xlsm.  Then I opened _Database.xlsm and ran the macro.  To my surprise, the file was written to the original path, not the new one.  And looking down at the Windows toolbar, I saw that Excel had opened the original file over in its original path as well.

After a lot of jiggering around with code tweaks, checking properties and such I finally found that I could prevent this by opening the copied spreadsheet, removing the Quick Access Toolbar button, re-adding it, and then saving the file.  My questions are:

1. Why isn't the macro "independently portable" along with the spreadsheet?  I.e. why does the copy maintain this kind of tie to the original sheet?
2. Is there a way I can create or modify the macro to make it portable in that sense?

Comment: If you want a toolbar/button to travel with a file (ie. not always link back to the original version) then you need to add it to the file itself, not to the QAT. The QAT only "knows" about the actual file you linked the button to. It might be better to add the macro to your Personal Macro Workbook and then just have it operate on the ActiveWorkbook.  Unless you want to distribute it to other users, in which case keep the macro in "database" workbook and add a custom ribbon part: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win001.htm

Comment: This is perfect - thanks!  If you make it an answer I can accept & upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a toolbar/button to travel with a file (ie. not always link back to the original version) then you need to add it to the file itself, not to the QAT. The QAT only "knows" about the actual file you linked the button to.

It might be better to add the macro to your Personal Macro Workbook and then just have it operate on the ActiveWorkbook.

However, if you want to distribute it to other users, you can keep the macro in the "database" workbook and add a custom ribbon part.  See: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win001.htm